# The first paragraph of "Leviathan Wakes" is driving me crazy. What do you think about it?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

I feel like the author gets his tenses all mixed up as soon as he finishes the prologue. At the very least, the first paragraph is difficult to parse. Check it out:

> A hundred and fifty years before, when the parochial disagreements
> between Earth and Mars **had been** on the verge of war, the Belt **had been** a
> far horizon of tremendous mineral wealth beyond viable economic reach,
> and the outer planets **had been** beyond even the most unrealistic
> corporate dream. Then Solomon Epstein **had built** his little modified
> fusion drive, popped it on to the back of his three-man yacht, and
> turned it on. With a good scope, you **could still see** his ship going at
> a marginal percentage of the speed of light, heading out into the big
> empty. The best, longest funeral in the history of mankind. The
> Epstein Drive **hadn't given** humanity the stars, but it **had delivered**
> the planets.

I'm having a hard time figuring out what the author is trying to say. Did humans get the Epstein Drive 150 years ago and start exploring the asteroid belt at *that* point? Or did they get it earlier, so that they already "had the planets" 150 years before the events in the prologue? Could you still see Epstein's ship with a telescope 150 years ago, or at the beginning of the story?

Comment: I don't see what's so difficult about it. Could you clarify what you don't understand?  Except for the first sentence, past perfect: *had been, had built, hadn't given, had delivered* means 150 years ago, and the past tense means "now". This is more or less the standard use of past perfect.

Comment: @PeterShor The author has already taken us 150 years into the past, so _had been_ should refer to a point even further back in time. If past perfect tense is correct here, we're learning about stuff that happened more than 150 years before the prologue. Suppose he'd written this: One hundred and fifty years ago, Earth and Mars were on the verge of war. The Belt was unreachable. Then Epstein built his fusion drive, turned it on, and took off into space.

Comment: You can see Epstein’s ship now, with a telescope, although he took off about 150 years ago.

Comment: @Xanne You seem to be reading this the way I am. Everything started 150 years ago, which means the author should be using the past tense, not the past perfect tense.

Comment: He’s the author; my view is you try to understand, not critique. The prologue refers to 150 years before the observation of the ship, which is likely to be before the time frame of the story.

Comment: @Xanne Thanks for your comments. My goal is to understand, but the writing gets in the way. I just want to see how others read the paragraph.

Comment: @NicholasLieurance: The book is written in past tense, so to say something happened 150 years before the rest of the book, the author uses past perfect. The reason that the first sentence contains *were on the verge of war* is that it's in a *when* clause, and tenses in *when* clauses are more flexible than tenses not in them.

Comment: For example, we would probably say *"I had been shown the secret passage when I was a boy,"* and not *"when I had been a boy."* An example from a famous author (Thackeray's *Barry Lyndon*): "I sat down on the old bench, where I had sat on the day when Nora jilted me; and I do believe my feelings were as strong then as they had been when I was a boy, eleven years before."

Comment: @PeterShor Now _that_ makes sense! The narrator tells the story in the past tense, so any backward step he takes from there is actually at least two steps back from his perspective. I'll have to chew on that for a bit.

Comment: @jsw29 Thanks for asking. I finished the book and I think I understand it just fine. But I'm a technical writer and I feel a strong need to know when I'm seeing a mistake. Every time I think I've spotted an error and someone shows me I'm wrong, I learn.